# How to find the coordinates of a regular polyhedron

Tags: group-theory

We well know that to find the coordinates of the vertices a polygon, we can simply solve the complex variable equation $z^n-1=0$ (and scale them as we wish).

Is there an analog method to find the coordinates of the vertices of a Platonic solid? 
For example something like solving an equation such as $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{n/2}-1 = 0$, for certain numbers $(x,y,z)$? and if so, how to solve this?

Thanks.

H.

Comment: The 2D and 3D cases do not compare. There is a regular polygon for any $n$. Regular polyhedra are sporadic.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for your answer. If I fixed two points of a  polygon, all other vertices are uniquely determined. If I fixed three points in a regular polyhedron, all other points are uniquely determined, so there should be an equation to find them. What would that equation be?

Comment: You can construct all vertices by rotations of the faces around the axis from the center to a vertex, with the amplitude that brings an edge onto another edge. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle

Answer (score -5):

When in doubt,  google.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid#Cartesian_coordinates

It's not a general formula but simply a statement of the 5 cases with graphical explanations why.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question; listing coordinates is not an analogous method to solving an equation.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for your contribution. I see in the website that you indicate, that all the coordinates are explicit in a table. Now, for example, for the cube they are (1,1,1)), (1,-1,-1), .... and so. I can then now tell that the cube satisfies the equations $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, |x|=|y|=|z|=1$. I have a hard time believing that there are on general equations. All of the satisfy the equation x^2+y^2+z^2=1, up to a scale.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo: hem, $1^2+1^2+1^2=3$. By symmetry the vertices belong to a sphere.

Comment: I said up to a scale. So I mean that each side has length $1/\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo Then avoid writing $x^2+y^2+z^2=1, |x|=|y|=|z|=1$.

Comment: You are correct, the equation is $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$, $|x|=|y|=|z|=1$. However this is not the point. I do not want to get distracted with algebraic details.  It is well known that an icosahedron could be represented with a quintic equation (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.0955.pdf) something similar should happen to the other Platonic solids using stereographic projections.

Comment: @Herman Vertices as solutions to a polynomial equation (for polygons) seems to be quite different from associating a polynomial to a polyhedron like the icosahedron. I'm not saying you won't be able to do what Klein did with the icosahedron for other solids, but I do not believe he produced a polynomial whose solutions $(x,y,z)$ were exactly the twenty vertices.

Comment: @pjs36 In fact equation 2.4 in my link above is the same as equation (1) in the wolfram link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IcosahedralEquation.html  This equation is an equation of degree 11. As "Wolfram" explains it is not degree 12, because the north pole is the vertex at infinity. So equation (1) of Wolfram is the equation for the vertices of an icosahedron but stereographically projected to the plane. Once that equation is solved (which could be a hard matter) each projected vertex can be backprojected to the sphere by finding the intersection of the vector line from vert. to the n. pole.

Comment: I believe that every one who indicated that there is no such a nice generalization to the equation z^n-1=0 to polyhedra is right. That there are equations whose roots are the vertices of polyhedra is a different question. Thank you all for your contributions. It seems that the problem is that complex theory is a very solid subject and $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not even close to have such a solid theory.